# How to retain props.location.state value if I refreshed

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

When enters first time a page contains `this.props.location.state` gets all state details but when refresh that page we get only undefined state. How to retains the value of `props.location.state` even if refreshes.
console of props on refresh as follow

```
logged props: undefined
```

Comment: you need to store the value in localStorage if you wish that it should persist on refresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an if-else block inside `componentDidMount()` which first checks if `this.props.location.state` exists. If it does then save it to localStorage/sessionStorage and go ahead with your logic. If it doesn't then check localStorage for the state, which would have been saved during the first load.

Inside your `componentDidMount()`:

```
let routeState
if(this.props.location.state){
    localStorage.setItem('routeState', JSON.stringify(this.props.location.state))
    routeState = this.props.location.state
} else {
    routeState = localStorage.getItem('routeState')
    if(routeState) routeState = JSON.parse(routeState)
}

if(routeState){
    //use routeState ahead
} else {
    //Prompt no data.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `HashRouter` use `browserRouter` then the data will get retained.

Comment: while using browserRouter whiteLable issue occur